# Private memory indexing OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am struggling with OpenCL [specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.0.pdf), as I find it sometimes ambiguous, can someone try to answer the following questions ?

Consider the following code :

```
__kernel void myKernel(...)
{    
    // Buffer 1
    __local float *buffer1[64];

    // Buffer 2
    __local float *buffer2;

    // Buffer 3
    __private float *buffer3[64];

    // Buffer 4
    float *buffer4[64];

    int var1 = 1, var2 = 2;
    nonKernelFunction(&var1, &var2);

    // ...

}

void nonKernelFunction(int *pvar1, int *pvar2)
{
    int *pvar;
    if (someRunTimeCondition)
        pvar = pvar1;
    else
        pvar = pvar2;
    *pvar += 1; 
}
```

1) Is there a difference (static or dynamic) between buffer1 and buffer2 ?

2) Are declarations of buffer3 and buffer4 equivalent (they are for variables, but I'm not sure for pointers) ?

3) On GPUs (where private memory is only registers I think), where will the compiler allocate the ressources ? If it is in global memory, is it possible to know how much memory will be used at run time, from the host ?

4) Assuming buffer3 and buffer4 are stored into registers, how can instructions like buffer3[i] = buffer4[i] (where i is known at run time) be allowed ?

5) If buffer3 and buffer4 are not stored into registers, then, how can nonKernelFunction code be allowed (var1 and var2 are definitely not in memory) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK :

1) there is no technical difference between static specifications in the kernel code and "dynamic" specification by the host via a buffer;

2) by default variables are __private so this should not make any difference;

3) private memory MAY be allocated in registers if small but otherwise global memory will be used;
you can query minimum memory requirements for a kernel using clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo;

4) why should they not be allowed, because it might result in out-of-bound errors ?

5) var1 and var2 are in the address-space of the GPU, even if not in the private memory; access might be slower that's all.

EDIT1 :
The fact that var1 and var2 are in registers, say reg1 and reg2, should not be an issue as the code could result in pseudo-assembly like :

```
myKernel:
    ...
    push reg1
    push reg2
    call nonKernelFunction
    ...

nonKernelFunction:
    test someRunTimeCondition
    jz ko
        mov [SP+2] reg1
        jmp end:
    ko:
        mov [SP+1] reg1
    end:
    mov [reg1] reg2
    inc reg2
    mov reg2 [reg1]
```

I don't know if GPUs assemblies/core-architectures are much different but on a standard CPU there is no issue because you use the stack to make abstraction of the effective locations.

Note that there is a more recent version of the spec here :) http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf

Comment: 1) 2) 3) Ok thanks.
4) - 5) No, I am wondering how the compiler can produce PTX code. Let me get back to my example: if var1 and var2 are stored into registers (say R1 and R2) then the compiler cannot translate the line "*pvar += 1" as it would mean increasing the value carried either by R1 or R2. And deciding which register to increase cannot be decided at compile time.